# using Python to represent merge-sort,how to avoid a IndexError

Tags: python, algorithm

I know it's not correct,and I have found [another  method](http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/01/basic-sorting-algorithms-implemented-in-python) without infinite number ,but I still want to know if it could be corrected with the usage of infinite number.

```
def MergeSort(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        mid = len(A) / 2
        left = A[0:mid]
        right = A[mid:]

        MergeSort(left)
        MergeSort(right)

        w = float("inf")
        left.append(w)
        right.append(w)
        i,j = 0,0
        for k in range(len(A)):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
                A[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                A[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the `for k in range(len(A)):` loop; what happens when you have exhausted all the values in `left` but there are values remaining in `right` (or vice-versa)?

The linked method adds a test which basically looks like

```
if (left still has values) and ((right has no values) or (next_left < next_right)):
    take a value from left
```

Your code above instead adds a guard value, ensuring that if you are on the left guard value it is guaranteed to be greater than any non-guard right value (and vice-versa). This is true until the `for` loop stops, with left and right each containing only the guard value.

Another option, [as seen here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html#lst-merge), is to loop until either left or right is exhausted, then have follow-up loops to collect the remaining values.

Comment: I'm still confused.....the for-loop run lenA times，when the A is merged,doesn't the loop stop ?

Comment: It does, and that works out, because you add two items (inf to left and inf to right), and when the loop finishes both items remain (neither left nor right is empty).

Comment: But my for-loop is only used to merge the two lists,and it needn't make the two list empty at last,is that right?......or I haven't understood your mean ?